# How can I generate a joint histogram of Gaussian partial derivatives of the image in x and y direction in python of a gray image?

Tags: python

I was hoping someone can help me on this topic. As I want to create a function which takes a grayscale image and number of bins as an arguments then compute the first derivatives then quantize derivatives to num_bins number of values and define 2d histogram with num_bins^2 number of entries and return hists.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance. This is what I have done

```
def dxdy_hist(img_gray, num_bins):

    # compute the first derivatives
    # ...
    xderiv = gaussian_filter(img_gray, sigma=(11,0))
    xderiv = gaussian_filter(img_gray, sigma=(0,11))

    # quantize derivatives to "num_bins" number of values
    # ...
    img_gray = img_gray.quantize(num_bins)

    # define a 2D histogram  with "num_bins^2" number of entries
    hists = np.zeros((num_bins, num_bins))

    # ...
    plt.hist2d(xderiv,yderiv,bins=num_bins^2)

    hists = hists.reshape(hists.size)
    return hists
```

Comment: Please show us how you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I am trying to figure out but cannot find anything that helps me

Comment: @rpoleski I have updated the question take a look now

Comment: 1) Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, I have no idea what type `img_gray` is. 2) Describe what the problem is. You posted some code but there is no indication of your issue. 3) You're setting `xderiv` twice and never `yderiv`.